# Use equivalent of proxy-config option in ng server to run ng e2e

Tags: angular, api, redirect, proxy

I'm using the proxy-config as described in other articles to redirect calls to in my Angular application to my back-end API. I use the following as my `proxy.conf.json` file:-

```
{
  "/comparison/api": {
    "target": "http://localhost:8080",
    "secure": false,
    "changeOrigin": true
  }
}
```

This works great, redirecting API calls to my Node/Express stub API service.

When I come to run E2E tests using the Angular CLI, there is no --proxy-config option. Does anyone know how I can set-up the same proxy redirect in the E2E Protractor tests?

Comment: it's an [open issue](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/6358). I run my e2e tests against the real API.

Answer (score 10):

Right now e2e doesn't support --proxy-config as an option. It's part of **Nice to Have** list.
ref - https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/6358

Here is the workaround for now.

**e2e** uses **ng serve** at the back and **ng serve** can be configured to use a proxy.

Modify the **serve** options in the **angular.json** file and add **proxyConfig**.

```
"serve": {
           "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
           "options": {
                 "browserTarget": "ChangeManagementPortal:build",
                 "proxyConfig": "proxy.conf.json"  
                }
```

Now ng e2e will run with the proxy redirect.

Comment: That worked pretty well. Thanks Sahoo Babu :)

Comment: Can you please suggest how to configure that in package.json ? e.g. if I want to run again different backends. now my npm start configuration is like this: 
'"start:localhost": "ng serve --proxy-config localhost.proxy.conf.json",
"start:qa1": "ng serve --proxy-config qa1.proxy.conf.json",
"start:qa2": "ng serve --proxy-config qa2.proxy.conf.json", '