# Running Angular E2E Tests with Custom Flags and Proxy Configuration in Cypress

Tags: angular, cypress, e2e-testing

I am facing an issue when trying to run end-to-end (E2E) tests for my Angular application using Cypress. The problem arises because my Angular app requires specific flags (--proxy-config, etc.) to run correctly, and I want to pass these flags when Cypress runs my application.

I've tried modifying the e2e script in my **package.json** like this:

```
"scripts": {
  "e2e": "ng e2e --port=4200 --proxy-config=./proxy.conf.json"
}
```

But I am receiving the error: 'Error: Unknown arguments: port, proxy-config'

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Use equivalent of proxy-config option in ng server to run ng e2e](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49329191/use-equivalent-of-proxy-config-option-in-ng-server-to-run-ng-e2e)